# Custom google login firebase

Tags: android, firebase, google-signin

I created an application with a Google login, I'm trying to figure out if there is a way I can customize the login window. I followed the official tutorial from https://firebase.google.com/docs/auth/android/google-signin to create the app. Thanks in advance

[image]

This is the login windows I want to customize

Comment: Which login window are you referring at?

Comment: check this http://codeneuron.com/blog/firebase_Auth.html